# I am getting a "no access" error after Oauth facebook login

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My buttons pop up and let me login but when it goes to redirect me to the next page, I get an error stating no access from the api and another error saying name isn't defined, I know name is defined because I had this working once before with the same code but then vscode did something stupid and broke it. Here is my code.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';
    import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';
    import {PostData} from '../../services/PostData';
    import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
    import './Welcome.css';

    class Welcome extends Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super (props);
        this.state = {
          loginError: false,
          redirect: false,
        };
        this.signup = this.signup.bind (this);
      }

      signup (res, type) {
        let postData;
        if (type === 'facebook' && res.email) {
          postData = {
            name: res.name,
            provider: type,
            email: res.email,
            provider_id: res.id,
            token: res.accessToken,
            provider_pic: res.picture.data.url,
          };
        }

        if (type === 'google' && res.w3.U3) {
          postData = {
            name: res.w3.ig,
            provider: type,
            email: res.w3.U3,
            provider_id: res.El,
            token: res.Zi.access_token,
            provider_pic: res.w3.Paa,
          };
        }

        if (postData) {
          PostData ('signup', postData).then (result => {
            let responseJson = result;
            sessionStorage.setItem ('userData', JSON.stringify (responseJson));
            this.setState ({redirect: true});
          });
        } else {
        }
      }

      render () {
        if (this.state.redirect || sessionStorage.getItem ('userData')) {
          return <Redirect to={'/home'} />;
        }

        const responseFacebook = response => {
          console.log ('facebook console');
          console.log (response);
          this.signup (response, 'facebook');
        };

        const responseGoogle = response => {
          console.log ('google console');
          console.log (response);
          this.signup (response, 'google');
        };

        return (
          <div>
            <FacebookLogin
              appId="2580971392000123"
              autoLoad={false}
              fields="name,email,picture"
              callback={responseFacebook}
            />
            <br /><br />

            <GoogleLogin
              clientId="234567891765550-duk7c1do3705dlj8i6dnsr27oe7rlaq3.apps.googleusercontent.com"
              buttonText="Login with Google"
              onSuccess={responseGoogle}
              onFailure={responseGoogle}
            />

          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Welcome;
```

So it goes from the welcome component to the Home component, here is the code for  Home where the error is.

```js
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import './Home.css';
    import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
    class Home extends Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super (props);
        this.state = {
          name: '',
          redirect: false,
          products: [],
          pid: '',
        };
      }

      componentDidMount () {
        let data = JSON.parse (sessionStorage.getItem ('userData'));
        console.log (data);

        this.setState ({name: data.userData.name});
      }

      render () {
        if (!sessionStorage.getItem ('userData') || this.state.redirect) {
          return <Redirect to={'/'} />;
        }

        if (this.state.pid > 0) {
          return <Redirect to={'/checkout'} />;
        }

        return (
          <div>
            Welcome {this.state.name}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Home;
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```js
    [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
    react-dom.development.js:20718 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: 
    log.js:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
    Home.js:17 {error: {…}}error: {text: "No access"}__proto__: Object
    Home.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
        at Home.componentDidMount (Home.js:19)
        at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:16855)
        at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:18210)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
        at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:18418)
        at completeRoot (react-dom.development.js:19875)
        at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:19804)
        at performWork (react-dom.development.js:19712)
```

I am new to React and coding in general, so sorry in advance if I sound stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means you don't have a valid token/login. Judging by the error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`, I'd say you're trying to get the `name` property from an object that does not contain it or does not exist (which is more likely). You may have defined `name`, but that definition is outside the scope of the `name` call.

> The Problem

You are trying to set `name` in `postData` to `res.name`, but `res.name` is never defined.

> The Solution

Find where `res` is created, and create or add the `name` property in the constructor.

Comment: This is a very common issue with new JavaScript users, so don't feel bad about it.